# How to change the style of a checkbox from holo.light to holo.dark?

Tags: android, checkbox, styles

The title speaks for itself. Is it possible? If so, than how do I do it? I want to use the holo.dark color scheme only for a `CheckBox`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your layout xml file 
`style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox"`

Comment: That's right in XML layout editor, or in graphical in properties view

Comment: nice solution, but not good for me since my min API is 7, not 11 :/

Comment: You are using AppCompat library or HoloEverywhere?

Comment: AppCombat (in style folder: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar)

Comment: Easiest way will be to make two layout folders one for every Android version, and second for 11+ Version
So make `layout` and `layout-v11` , XML in layout folder should be without style, and second one copy in `layout-v11` with this Widget.Holo.CompundButton.Checkbox

Comment: I guess that is my only way out (not a brilliant way, but still at least a pavement). Thanks :)

Comment: Making copy of the layout its not the best way. If you are familiar with themes and styles it would be better to make values and values-v11 with other styles to make other styles files and only one layout file.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using android-studio, select your checkbox, and in the properties, set 'buttonTint' property value to whatever color you want using the editor. Or , if you prefer the xml solution, use

```
android:buttonTint="@color/white"
```

This assumes of course that the color white is defined.

Comment: It requires api lvl 21